# bootstrap3 margin/padding affecting endpoint of jsPlumb

Tags: jquery, css, jsplumb

I am using Bootstrap3 and trying to make use of the jsPlumb library (https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/). In my bootstrap layout I have a navbar, then the main content goes into a container-fluid div.

The issue is, as per the bootstrap documentation, to ensure the content of the container-fluid isn't hidden under the nav bar, I need to add padding to push the content down below the nav bar. This works fine, except its having a negative impact on where the endpoint is position on the div by jsplumb.

Below is my HTML

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper" style="z-index: 4000;">
    <div class="container" style="z-index: 4000;">
        <nav class="navbar-md navbar-inverse navbar-static-top navbar-fixed-top" style="z-index: 4000;">
            <div class="container" style="z-index: 4000;">
                <div class="navbar-header" style="z-index: 4000;">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                    <a style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 5px;" class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img style="height: 90px;" src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="z-index: 4000;">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    </ul>
</div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9 content">

                    <div id="canvas">
                        <div id="start-block" class="flow-block">
                            <p class="title">Start Block</p>
                            <p id="mainContent"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9 sidebar">
                    <p>Sidebar Content</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

If I remove the padding the endpoint is position correctly, except the start-block div is off the screen under the navbar.

Screenshot of what I am seeing is below:

[image: Screenshot showing issue with endpoint incorrectly positioned]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/82081/)

Comment: make a working demo so we could check the issue!

Comment: I've created this jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/82081/). I've removed the sidebar from the example as it looked a little more confusing as it goes into a mobile layout

Comment: May have partly fixed it myself. I added #canvas and set position to relative (I thought was the default). So the endpoint is in the right place, but when I drag the div, the endpoint moves, but the div stays where it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure the problem out, I guess bootstrap makes objects act differently to the default (I tested the library first on a blank HTML/Jquery page - no bootstrap).

I added the position relative to the canvas parent and the flow-block class I added position absolute and that seems to have resolved the issue I was seeing.

Comment: If possible can you please share a reproducible JSfiddle. Thanks a lot in advance.